# How use interface in function, where argument is another interface, that have same list of functions?

Tags: go

I have trouble with interfaces in function arguments.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A interface {
    New() A
    B()
    C()
}

type B interface {
    New() B
    B()
}

type AS struct {}
func (AS) New() A {
    return AS{}
}

func (AS) B() {}
func (AS) C() {}

func Hello(b B) {
    b.New()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    as := AS{}
    a := A(as)
    Hello(a)
}
```

I've got this error:

```
tmp/sandbox293137995/main.go:35: cannot use a (type A) as type B in argument to Hello:
A does not implement B (wrong type for New method)
    have New() A
    want New() B
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dwNWx2kqy2)

How can I refactor this code, if I want use interface A in function Hello?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of having the `New()` method on the interface? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense, and it's what your error stems from.

Comment: Don't try to reproduce classical OOP in Go. You'll hurt yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to able to use interface `A` anywhere that interface `B` is accepted, `A` has to implement **all** the methods defined in `B`. So that includes `New() B` and `B()`.

Essentially, you can embed `B` in `A` like this:

```
type A interface {
  NewA() A
  C()
  B
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/qmtMxRBnsn).

Notice that in my example, I still have to implement all the methods of both `A` and `B` in the `AS` struct.

I also have to rename the 2 `New()` functions. In Go, you can't have 2 functions in the same package with the same name, even though their return values are different.

In general, you don't need to provide constructors in interface, because structs can be created without them.

Comment: And having a "constructor" in an interface is highly counter-intuitive, because you expect to execute the methods on an instance. Calling a constructor on an existing instance is nonsensical.